# Running Google Closure compiler with grunt

Tags: node.js, requirejs, gruntjs, google-closure-compiler, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am trying to create a grunt task to build a javascript project using requirejs with closure compiler as the optimizer. I am using the grunt-contrib-requirejs plugin.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-requirejs

Although I haven't explicitly setup the closure compiler, here is the config and the error:

Config:

```
requirejs:
      compile:
        options:
          sourceMap: true
          baseUrl: "client"
          mainConfigFile: "main.js"
          name: "main.js"
          out: "build/main.js"
          optimize: "closure"
          #generateSourceMaps: true
          closure:
            CompilerOptions: {},
            CompilationLevel: 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS'
            loggingLevel: 'WARNING'
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Project>grunt requirejs
Running "requirejs:compile" (requirejs) task
{ [Error: Error: optimizer with name of "closure" not found for this environment

    at Object.optimize.js (C:\Users\Project\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:24771:27)
]
  originalError: [Error: optimizer with name of "closure" not found for this env
ironment] }
```

Closure is written in java and my project is in nodejs and I'm not sure how to set it up right.

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation states that Closure as an optimizer can only be used when running requirejs in Java](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L103). You're running requirejs in Node which is JavaScript, not Java.

You can work around this issue by doing it in two separate steps:

1. Run the RequireJs task, output to a temporary file
2. Run another task that Closure-compiles the temporary file to the final file

[You can use this Grunt package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-closure-compiler)  if you want to run the Closure Java binary on your own machine. Alternatively, you could use [my Grunt Closure script that uses Closure REST API](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-gcc-rest), which doesn't require Java or the Closure binary to be installed on your system.